# Avoiding Type Erasure when implementing the Repository Pattern

Tags: swift, generics, type-erasure

I'm trying to implement the repository pattern in Swift in a generic way. The problem that I'm currently facing is, that it seems like I have to write type erasure wrappers for all my repositories. Am I missing something here? Is there a better way to do this or to make the compiler happy at this point?

```swift
// 1
class Item {}

// 2
protocol Repository {
    associatedtype T
}

// 3
protocol AnyItemRepository: Repository where T == Item {}

// 4
class ItemRepository: AnyItemRepository {
    static let shared = ItemRepository()

    private init() {}
}

// 5
class ViewController {

    // 6
    var itemRepository: AnyItemRepository? = ItemRepository.shared

}
```

1. One of many entities
2. The base repository interface that can be extended if necessary or implemented directly
3. A special item repository interface that guarantees additional functionality on top of the base repository
4. Concrete repository implementation for a specific entity type
5. Some class that needs to access the data
6. Dependency to any item repository. The compiler errors on this line: `Protocol 'AnyItemRepository' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you're planning to use this Repository for. Repository is designed for environments that have certain characteristics (such as strong linkages to row-style databases). I'll discuss other patterns that often work better in common iOS apps (and even smaller Mac apps).

I usually strongly dislike type erasure, and it often indicates a design problem. But in this case I think type erasure might be a reasonable answer.

So we'll start with the kinds of items we can store. They probably are going to need to have some kind of identifier, and be hashable for many common backends (but maybe you won't need hashing; if not, take it out).

```
protocol Identified {
    associatedtype ID
    var id: ID { get }
}

typealias Storable = Identified & Hashable
```

And then there are things that can act as storage. There is no such thing as a "RepositoryStorage." This is just saying "if you comply with these requirements, then Repository can use you."

```
protocol RepositoryStorage {
    associatedtype Item: Storable

    func get(identifier: Item.ID) -> Item?
    func add(item: Item)
    func delete(identifier: Item.ID)
    func allItems() -> [Item]
}
```

And then the standard, somewhat tedious, type-eraser pattern (there's another pattern that stdlib uses that even more tedious, but this one is good enough for most cases).

```
// I'm making it a class because I assume it'll have reference semantics.
final class Respository<Item: Storable>: RepositoryStorage {

    init<Storage: RepositoryStorage>(storage: Storage) where Storage.Item == Item {
        self._get = storage.get
        self._add = storage.add
        self._delete = storage.delete
        self._allItems = storage.allItems
    }

    let _get: (Item.ID) -> Item?
    func get(identifier: Item.ID) -> Item? { return _get(identifier) }

    let _add: (Item) -> Void
    func add(item: Item) { _add(item) }

    let _delete: (Item.ID) -> Void
    func delete(identifier: Item.ID) { _delete(identifier) }

    let _allItems: () -> [Item]
    func allItems() -> [Item] { return _allItems() }
}
```

So that's fine, it's a general-purpose Repository. And this makes reasonable sense if you're dealing with a large set of items that are probably going to be stored in a SQLite database. But in my experience it is often both too much and too little. Too much if it's just a few items, and too little if you have a lot of items and so probably have to do a lot more than just CRUD. You probably need Query and Join, and then this isn't enough. (Making something flexible in one direction often cuts you off in other directions. There's no universal "generic.")

So can we make it simpler for the case when it's really just a few items? Here's an approach I use regularly:

```
class DataStore<Key: Hashable & Codable, Value: Codable> {
    let identifier: String
    private(set) var storage: DataStorage

    var dictionary: [Key: Value] {
        didSet {
            storage[identifier] = try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(dictionary)
        }
    }

    init(identifier: String, storage: DataStorage = UserDefaults.standard) {
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.storage = storage

        let data = storage[identifier] ?? Data()
        self.dictionary = (try? PropertyListDecoder().decode([Key: Value].self,
                                                             from: data)) ?? [:]
    }

    subscript(key: Key) -> Value? {
        get { return dictionary[key] }
        set { dictionary[key] = newValue }
    }
}
```

A DataStore acts as dictionary that you can store key/value pairs in:

```
let ds = DataStore<String: Item>(identifier: "Item")
ds["first"] = item
```

It can store anything Codable. With a little modification, you could switch it from a dictionary-like interface to an array or set-like interface; I just usually want a dictionary.

When it's updated, it encodes the entire data store to its storage as Data:

```
protocol DataStorage {
    subscript(identifier: String) -> Data? { get set }
}
```

This is very fast and efficient for dozens of items. I might rethink if if there were over a hundred items, and it would be inappropriate for hundreds or more items. But for small sets, this is very, very fast.

A very common DataStorage is UserDefaults:

```
extension UserDefaults: DataStorage {
    subscript(identifier: String) -> Data? {
        get { return data(forKey: identifier) }
        set { set(newValue, forKey: identifier) }
    }
}
```

The key lesson is that this gets rid of all the type-erasure hoop-jumping by creating a common currency (Data) that lower layers work exclusively with. Any time you can do that, separating the upper-layer generic interface from a lower-layer non-generic interface, you'll save yourself a lot of tedium.

This may or may not work for your situation. It's tailored to key/value stores rather than databases, and it's designed to be read much more often than written. But for that usage, it's much simpler and generally faster than the Repository pattern. That's the kind of trade-offs I mean when I say that it's important to know your use case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Rob. I really appreciate the effort you've put into this. Probably the pattern is totally overkill for my use case but I want to put as much time into it as it takes to really understand it. My codebase already looks pretty much exactly like what you've suggested at first. I also feel like it's fine to write a type erasure wrapper for the general-purpose repository. However having to write type erasure wrappers for every specialized repository seems like I'm doing something wrong. Would you say I have to do it anyways and it's just a inconvenience I have to accept?

Comment: I would say that you should start with what your specialized repositories actually are, and build up from there. If you're building tons of type-erasers, you're almost certainly doing something wrong. As you say "is probably overkill for my use case." Focus on your use case. Don't create problems you don't have. There is no such thing as a "general" solution to a unbounded problem. When you put bonds on the problem, then we can build solutions that live in those bounds.

Comment: So, how many implementations of Repository do you currently have, and what are they? (If the answer is "one," then stop. Using generics is actively harmful in that case. It's boxing you in such that it will be harder to make the system flexible in the future when you discover the actual axis you need flexibility along.)

Comment: Thank you for your advice Rob. I'm going to have 6 repositories for this app. The main reason for me building this app is improving my Swift knowledge. That's why I'm not too concerned about it being overkill. It's basically a learning side project.

Comment: Overkill doesn't equate to deeper knowledge, though. If you really want to expand your Swift understanding, build a use case that actually needs the flexibility, and then explore different ways to solve it. I've been working on this project much of today because I think it can be sliced more wisely than a type eraser. My use case is a single engine that can support a CloudKit backend and a Dictionary backend. Here's my current fully type-erased solution that I'm working to remove the type eraser from. https://gist.github.com/rnapier/03627315078286415214615399552ed7

Comment: Interesting gist. Thank you for sharing it with us. I will reevaluate my architecture. Maybe I can come up with something more appropriate.

Comment: You might want to read my updated FURTHER THOUGHT section at the top. I realized that even my use case had no mapping onto the real world (CloudKit doesn't work that way).

Comment: Thank you for your further thought. I like the stdlib type-eraser pattern you‘re using there. It doesn‘t limit one when it comes to method naming etc.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `AnyItemRepository` type. Just write extension methods on `Repository` like so:

```
public extension Repository where T == Item {
   func doSomethingSpecial(with items: [Item]) {
      // blah blah
   }
}
```

In your view controller, you can't use `Repository` or `AnyItemRepository` in this way because these are *generic type constraints*. You must either use a concrete type or generically parameterize `ViewController`.

```
class RepositoryViewController<R>: UIViewController where R: Repository, R.T == Item {
    var itemRepository: R { get }
}

class ViewController: RepositoryViewController<ItemRepository> {
   override var itemRepository: ItemRepository {
      return ItemRepository.shared
   }
}
```

(The above is untested pseudocode designed to give you the gist. It has never been run by anyone ever and may not even compile.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Gregory. I have already tried a very similar solution like the one you are suggesting and I like the idea a lot. However it turns out that generically parameterized classes are not supported by storyboards.